# hitTestObject between objects in two arrays in two different classes

Tags: actionscript-3

In my Main class I have an array of Enemy objects, and in my Player class I have an array of Bullet objects. Somewhere amongst this I need a method which tests for collision between any player bullet and an enemy, and when a collision is detected call the Bullet's destroyBullet() method and the Enemy's destroyEnemy() method.

I could probably figure out how this would be done if both arrays were within the same class, but otherwise I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason to not also hold your bullets array in your main class, but if you want to do this as you have it you'll need public access to Player.bullets

This should work from your main class. You will want to put this inside of a checkCollisions function that runs in your game loop.

```
//loop through bullets first, because if no bullets are fired, no point in checking
for each(var bullet:Bullet in player.bullets) {
  for each(var enemy:Enemy in enemies) {
    if(bullet.hitTestObect(enemy)) {
      bullet.destroyBullet();
      enemy.destroyEnemy();
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that destroying a bullet or enemy will involve more than removing the sprite and cleanup. You'll also need to splice the arrays that each object is stored in.

Comment: Thanks for the help. For the most part I've got everything working, but I ran into one problem and I've only just figured out why it's happening. I've modified the game slightly so that instead of just destroying the enemy after one bullet collides with it, it now has 200 health, and decrements by 1 every time a bullet hits the enemy. Only problem is, the hitTestObject only seems to run the first time a bullet collides with the enemy, so after this has happened the health stays at 199 and every bullet after the first one passes through the enemy instead of deleting itself.

Comment: Because this is a game and this will presumably run fairly often, you should do two things here: 1) Switch from an Array to a Vector (much, much faster) and 2) Lose the `for each` and go with a standard `for` loop which is, again, much faster. See [this article](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/358) about loop speeds. That should reduce your loop time nearly 66%

Comment: Disregard my last comment, I just realised I was having it splice the enemy as well as the bullet on every hitTest. whoops.

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 Directly in that article it states that 10.1 performance update for-each was 2.5 times faster, so I guess it depends on which player you are targeting, but I do agree about using Vector

Comment: @Helto That was actually in another article linked to in the comments, thus why I had never seen it. Regardless, that is good to know. I have always avoided for each loops because they were substantially slower than standard for loops. Thanks for pointing that one out.